# Function naming: choosing the order of nouns / verbs in the name

Tags: naming, naming-standards

I'm sometimes torn between two naming conventions defining the order of words that make up a function name. The first one is choosing the words in the same order we would natural use in a sentence, for example:

```
getFilters(...)
getPairedFilters(...)
getUniquePairedFilters(...)
```

This reads rather naturally but it's not immediately obvious that all of those functions return filters. Only the last part of the function name indicates that. If the name is long, that's not as convenient as the following:

```
getFilters(...)
getFiltersPaired(...)
getFiltersPairedUnique(...)
```

This, however, does not read as naturally but the names immediately suggest that they all return filters. Is there some sort of a consensus what name ordering is "better"?

Comment: As the numbers multiply, my vote would be for `getFilters().paired().unique()` etc...

Comment: That assumes that getFiltersPairedUnique can be implemented doing three function calls.

Comment: I mean what they return is in the signature right? like `getFilters(...): Filter[]` and `getUniquePairedFilters(...): Filter[]` you know it returns filters because that's what the return type is.

Comment: *it's not immediately obvious that all of those functions return filters* Really? Seems very obvious to me.

Comment: I disagree with the presumptive binary choice. The entire method signature and assignment influences naming.  Naming patterns like the filters examples is often parameters hiding in the name. Often, when signaling the return type it is not a morphed object type,  rather a collection/set. Good (receiving) variable names can help take care of that.  Polymorphic naming in context is a significant hint about underlying object and code design.

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 is correct. English is universal.

According to 2, a function called `isTimeSet()` should be named `isSetTime()` which is completely wrong.

Also functions named `getWeekDefinition()` and `getMonthDefinition()` whould turn into `getDefinitionWeek()` and `getDefinitionMonth()` respectively, which is wrong.

By using number 1, thankfully, we all know that `getWeekDefinition()` gives us a Definition object and not a Week object.

Comment: "should be named `isSetTime()`"  -- I did not make that conclusion from #2 since the word `Filters` == noun and `Paired` == adjective. whereas `Set` == verb.  #2 changes the order of nouns and adjectives.

Comment: @MarcelWilson Set, in `isTimeSet()` is the past participle of the verb to set, used as an adjective, not unlike Paired is the past participle of the verb to pair, used as an adjective. The real verb in ' isTimeSet()` is "is" (to be).

Answer (score -3):

Generally the only people reading function names are programmers. Given that most code factories are under severe deadlines the problem becomes which is the fastest way to exclude possibilities so that the coder can quickly find what they're looking for. So the best solution would be your second (not "get" so ignore, not "filters" so ignore, select appropriate remainder).

Comment: Let me just say that I completely disagree. People read a short name like getUniquePairedFilters completely and now directly what it means, because it is correct English.

Comment: Yeah, time is limited so let's add some puzzles. Makes perfect sense.